# C++ Average VectorXcd along axis

Tags: c++, vector, average, eigen, connectivity

I am a beginner in C++ programming. I try working with arrays and the Eigen module. Now I came across a problem I could solve in hours. Maybe it is pretty basic, but I am lost.

```
QPair<int, double> ConnectivityMeasures::calcImaginaryCoherence(const RowVectorXd& vecFirst, const RowVectorXd& vecSecond, int iNumberEpochs)
{
    Eigen::FFT<double> fft;

    int N = std::max( vecFirst.cols(), vecSecond.cols() ) ;

    //Compute the NFFT
    int b = ceil( log2(2.0 * N - 1) ) ;
    int fftsize = pow(2,b) ;

    //Zero Padding --> Cropping/Extending the Signal to the NFFT size. Cropping=Deleting Values; Extending=Fill up with Zeros
    RowVectorXd xImCohInputVecFirst = RowVectorXd::Zero(fftsize) ;
    xImCohInputVecFirst.head(vecFirst.cols() ) = vecFirst ;

    RowVectorXd xImCohInputVecSecond = RowVectorXd::Zero(fftsize) ;
    xImCohInputVecSecond.head( vecSecond.cols() ) = vecSecond ;

    //FFT for freq domain to both vectors
    RowVectorXcd freqvec ;
    RowVectorXcd freqvec2 ;

    fft.fwd(freqvec, xImCohInputVecFirst) ;
    freqvec.conjugate() ;
    fft.fwd(freqvec2, xImCohInputVecSecond) ;
    freqvec2.conjugate() ;

    // Calculate PowerSpectralDensitiy (PSD) and CrossSpectralDensity(CSD)
    VectorXcd Rxy(iNumberEpochs, fftsize);
    VectorXcd Rxx(iNumberEpochs, fftsize);
    VectorXcd Ryy(iNumberEpochs, fftsize);

    for (int i = 0; i < iNumberEpochs; i++)
    {
        Rxy[i] = sqrt( pow((freqvec[i].real() * freqvec2[i].real() + freqvec[i].imag() * freqvec2[i].imag()), 2 ) + pow((freqvec[i].real() * freqvec2[i].imag() + freqvec[i].imag() * freqvec2[i].real()), 2) );
        Rxx[i] = ( pow(freqvec[i], 2) );
        Ryy[i] = ( pow(freqvec2[i], 2) );
    }




// Average PSD, CSD over the Number of Epochs; not over channels
RowVectorXcd Rxy_mean(freqvec) = Rxy.mean() ;
RowVectorXcd Rxx_mean(freqvec) = Rxx.mean() ;
RowVectorXcd Ryy_mean(freqvec2) = Ryy.mean() ;
```

So my problem starts here. I have a 2D Array for my Rxy, Rxx and Ryy values. Stored like [number of epochs, number of frequencies].

Now I want to average all frequency values of each epoch to a single value and store them as **Rxy_mean, Ryy_mean and Rxx_mean**

My Compiler spit out *' Syntax error: missing ";" before "=" '*

Does anyone can say how to fix this, proceed or point out my mistake with a simple example ?

Thanks in advance,
    Daniel

Comment: The `mean()` of a `VectorXcd` is just a `std::complex<double>`. I'm not sure what you want to express with `RowVectorXcd Rxy_mean(freqvec)`, etc, but you can't directly assign something directly to it (similar as `std::vector<int> A(10)=std::vector<int>(5);` does not work).

Comment: Another thing that will fail at runtime: `VectorXcd Rxy(iNumberEpochs, fftsize);` will not work, unless `fftsize` is 1. Do you want a `MatrixXcd` maybe?

Comment: Tahnk you very much. It happens that we solved the problems nearly simultaneously. I also found the MatrixXcd failure. I really appreciate your effort.

Comment: Could you summarize what you did to fix it as an answer (and accept that), so this will not be listed as an open question?